# fixing memory leaks when you're returning the leaked memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

How do you fix a memory leak where you're returning from the function the leak itself?

For example, I make a `char* returnMe = new char[24324];` returnMe is what ends up getting returned from the function.  How do you account for this memory leak?  How do you destroy it once it's been returned?  I have some memory management rules in place that throw runtime errors on memory leaks to stop this, so I can't really ignore it.

Orrr am I a fool and this isn't a leak, implying that the leak is elsewhere?

Comment: It is only a leak if you have no reference to it anymore and therefore no was to free it.

Comment: despite my example, it starts out as an array of BYTE and is cast to a char* on return, since the function return char*.  could this be the cause?

Comment: @Shhnap: a precision on your remark: if you have a reference to it FROM the stack. If two elements reference each other but cannot be accessed from the stack, it leaked...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not a leak if you return it (well, it's not *your* leak).

You need to think in terms of resource ownership. If you return an allocated buffer from your function, *the caller of the function* is now responsible for it. The API should make it clear that it needs to be freed when they're finished with it.

Whether they free it themselves or pass it to another of your functions to have it freed (encapsulation in case more needs to be done than just freeing the memory) is another issue for the API.

Answer (score 3):

You can still `delete[]` the pointer `returnMe` even after it is returned.  It is not a memory leak unless you forget to delete `returnMe`.

Comment: Umm...that's delete [] returnMe. delete returnMe will usually work, but isn't actually correct.

Answer (score 2):

If your function is made to return an allocated buffer, there's no leak. Better, there's a leak if the client code on purpose calls your routine and does not do anything with what it returns, but in that case, it's the client code that is violating your contract.

When the buffer gets returned, it's controlled by the client code. In general, it's a good idea for solid programming to let allocation/deallocation happen at the same layer. Meaning that if you have a routine that returns a buffer, you should have a corresponding routine that deallocates it, even if the client code could call a delete[].

For example: suppose you have this code

```
char *mylib_gimmeh_buffer() {
    char* returnMe = new char[24324];
    return returnMe;
}
```

For symmetry you should have also

```
char *mylib_free_buffer(buffer) {
    delete[] buffer;
}
```

Now, your client code should behave like this

```
buf = mylib_gimmeh_buffer();
/* do something with buf */
mylib_free_buffer(buf);
```

if your client does something like this

```
mylib_gimmeh_buffer(); // just for fun
```

or like this

```
buf = mylib_gimmeh_buffer();
/* do something with buf */
/* never call mylib_free_buffer() */
```

then there's a memory leak

Answer (score 1):

```
char* function()
{
   char* returnMe = new char[24324];
   return returnMe;
}

int main()
{
   char* pGetReturnME = function();
   delete [] pGetReturnME;
}
```

You can still release the memory allocated in a function only if you have a pointer to the allocated memory. If the function returns you the pointer to the memory allocated you can release using `delete` or `delete[]`.

You have to be careful in having a clear protocol of allocation and deallocation of memory to avoid multiple deletion or memory leak.

Comment: Please, no `void main()`. See http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Answer (score 1):

The calling function is responsible for freeing the returned memory.

```
void function() {
    char *to_free = NULL;
    //to_free does not need to be freed yet

    to_free = function_that_uses_new_to_set_return();

    //to_free now must be freed if that function worked
    if (to_free != NULL) delete[] to_free;
}
```

Comment: You certainly don't want to call `free` on a pointer that has been allocated with `new`. You should edit this post to change `free` to `delete[]`

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible to have a function that allocates memory and returns a pointer to it, it's really error-prone... every time someone calls that function, they need to know that the function will be allocating memory on their behalf, and they need to know that they are responsible for freeing that memory, and they need to know the appropriate way to free the memory when they are done with it (delete?  delete[]?  free()?  Something else?), and they need to make sure that free happens exactly once, in all cases, and they need to make sure never to dereference the pointer again after the free occurs.

Inevitably in a non-trivial program, someone (possibly you!) will get one of those things wrong.  Then someone (probably you) will get to spend several hours of quality time with a debugger (or if you're lucky, valgrind) tracking down why your program is sometimes crashing or leaking memory.  It's really not much fun.

Fortunately in C++ there are better ways to do this that are much harder for the caller to screw up.  For example, instead of returning a raw pointer, you can return a [shared_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) that will automatically delete the allocated memory when the last pointer to it goes away.  That way nobody has to think about memory management, it "just works".

Once you get used to doing it that way, you'll never want to go back!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to return the memory in a way that's hard to leak. E.g. return it as a `boost::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter (since you need delete[]). Now it actually takes effort by the caller to leak.